# How to set image URI in HashMap

Tags: java, android, image, hashmap, uri

I am building a listview and i get the URI of an image wich i want to a HashMap using map.put.

The functions to get the URI works fine i can set an image View using setImageURI(uri).

What value should i use in the map.put("flag", value);

The following code is part of the postexecute

```
try {
                 android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                 oslist.clear();
                 for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                     JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                 String counter = c.getString(TAG_COUNTER);
                 String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                 String phono = c.getString(TAG_PHONO);
                 String error = c.getString(TAG_ERROR);

                 cur.moveToFirst();
                 cur.moveToPosition(i);
                 name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));

                 Uri uri = getPhotoUri(Long.parseLong(fetchContactIdFromPhoneNumber(phono)));

                 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 map.put("flag", value);
                 map.put(TAG_COUNTER, name);
                 map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                 map.put(TAG_PHONO, phono);
                 map.put(TAG_ERROR, error);
                 oslist.add(map);
                 list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_addcontact);
                 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                     R.layout.list_item,
                     new String[] {"flag",TAG_COUNTER, TAG_PHONO, TAG_ERROR}, new int[] {
                         R.id.flag,R.id.txtView_name, R.id.txtview_number, R.id.txtview_check});
                 list.setAdapter(adapter);

                 }

        }
```

thanks all for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you absolutely have to have the Uri in a Map of a String to a String? If so, you can get the String representation of the Uri with `uri.toString()` and then retrieve the Uri from the map by doing `Uri.parse(string)`.

Otherwise I'd just create a `HashMap<String, Parcelable>`

Comment: @Cigogne-Eveillee thanks for helping but searching i have found that you can not set Direct web url to ImageView for setting ImageView src. you first create an custom Adapter by extending BaseAdapter for ListView

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to download image, save it to a file, then load it into the ImageView